# How to slave a new light to an existing pull chain light

Tags: switch, light

We recently remodeled our house and had new outdoor lights installed. Well after the fact that only one works. We realized that the one that doesn't was on a pull chain. Well I'm not the smartest electrician so I'm wondering how to fix the issue. One light runs off the switch. I'd like to make both lights work on the same switch. I believe that they are running from the same wires.

Comment: Please clarify:  The only switch involved in this would be the pull chain switch on a light bulb socket, right?  (Not a wall mounted switch.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to *not* run off a pull chain, simply change the lamp base to a non-pull chain type.  The latter are $2.

If you want both lights to work off the pull chain and not the switch (why????) then shop around for lamp bases which have pull chains and also have attachment screws on the lamp base in the right places, i.e. A third screw between pull chain and switch.  Attach to that screw and neutral of course.

In either case, you would want to feed one lamp's power from the other lamp.  There are many Q&A on here how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

### For a 3 wire set up:

In my house, when this happens there's generally a 3 wire setup, black (hot switched), red(hot constant) and white (Neutral), as well as a green ground (the green doesn't count in your number of wires).  Black and Red may be different for your setup, so crack open the working switched light and see what colors are connected to it, then connect those same colors to the second light.

### If you only have 2 wires (plus a ground):

In some cases your light switch might be down stream of your unswitched light, in which case you should pull new wire because your alternative (change the unswitched fixture to a neutrally switched light) is against code / could get someone killed.

### Better than pulling new wire:

Just get a wifi (or zwave) switch and a smart bulb (or bulbs depending on your switch setup) and an appropriate hub if you don't already have one, then set up both lights to work in tandem via the hub.

Answer (score -2):

It’s easy. All I did was wire the 2 lights in serial fashion instead of parallel. Worked perfectly. Only potential drawback is if one bulb dies, both of them will go out. But my attic lights get used so infrequently the bulbs have lasted 10-15 years. If I switched to LED they would outlive me.

Comment: How about providing a wiring diagram of what you're suggesting. This doesn't sound right...

Comment: @FreeMan It's series-connected, so it's half voltage (for two bulbs that are the same wattage), and probably violates code in some way, though I don't have chapter and verse to hand to say how. I think it's OK for a fixture to be internally wired this way, but I strongly doubt that it's OK for two separate devices to be wired this way (at minimum it's "violating device maker's instructions" for supply voltage.)

Comment: As @Ecnerwal stated, you're creating a series circuit which acts as a voltage divider. While it may "work" for incandescent lighting it is incorrect and would cause problems with anything that may find itself on that circuit in the future. Further, I would bet if you switched to LED they probably wouldn't light up.

Answer (score -3):

How to wire 2 lights in serial with one pull chain.
[image]

Comment: You appear to need to visit this help page: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts